# Ways to reduce the disk size of Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, disk-space, performance, disk-cleanup

According to Microsoft's [documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947311) an installation of XP SP3 peaks at 1.5GB

However, in my case the actual size of `C:\WINDOWS` is 12 GB, amounting to a ten-fold difference.

Neither **CCleaner** nor **Disk Cleanup** were able to find anything significant but obviously something must be hiding somewhere.

A quick scan with **WinDirStat** revealed the following:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Installer               4.3 GB
C:\WINDOWS\system32                1.7 GB
C:\WINDOWS\$hf_mig$                1.4 GB
C:\WINDOWS\assembly                1.3 GB
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET           780 MB
C:\WINDOWS\ServicePackFiles        588 MB
C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution    485 MB
```

Any tools or suggestions for wiping at least some of it?

Comment: AFAIK a vanilla (completely clean) install of XPSP3 will indeed peak at 1.5GB, but once you start throwing years worth of updates at it the size will increase dramatically. 12GB does seem a bit excessive though.

Comment: I tried installing XPSP3 on a netbook with a 4GB SSD.  I could get everything installed for a vanilla instance with the exception of one .Net update.  But I was pushing ~3.7GB without hard disk compression.

Comment: You can always use nLite. Just crop off everything you can and there you go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The **Installer** directory contains
  details of programs you have
  installed. So it will grow and grow
  as you install new programs. To
  reduce it you could uninstall some
  programs you don't use. The sheer
  size of this directory suggest to me
  that either you must have a lot of
  programs installed or there are lots
  of duplicate files. How many programs do you have at the moment?
- Since you have .NET installed it will
  use quite a lot of space and the
  sizes for the **Microsoft.NET** and **assembly** folders look quite normal.
  I doubt Microsoft factor this in when
  they quote 1.5GB. If you don't use
  any .NET applications I think you
  should be able to remove .NET via the
  Control Panel -> Add / Remove
  Programs, although you could find
  this breaks something.
- Have you checked you don't have a lot
  of old System Restore files left
  over? They will inflate the size of
  the **system32** folder quite
  considerably.